# using .load() then JQuery code not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-load

I tried using this simple implementation to replace an image by any selected image from a gallery of thumbnails. The problem comes in when I use the .load() function and replace my current div class named "replace" with a new div such as NYC with a gallery from there. After the gallery is replaced, the first function no longer works.

```
<script>
    $('.replace #thumbs img').click(function(){ 
        $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
    });
</script>




<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".NYC" ).click(function() {
            $(".replace").load("Galleries.html #NYC");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why you have space in between Galleries.html #NYC ? .load( "Galleries.html#NYC");

Comment: thats irrelevant i can change it back

Comment: i am calling the NYC div to replace the current gallery & large image from Galleries.html

Comment: with load method you don't have space in between URL @Max

Comment: @surajrawat The space separates the URL from a selector for [loading a page fragment](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments).

Comment: Then look at your code and lets make it mode simple by doing this 

 $('#largeImage').attr('src','large');

Comment: can you show your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery on to register your first click such as:

```
<script>
    $('.replace').on('click', '#thumbs img', function(){ 
        $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have missed a ' in your selector. It should be $('.replace')

Comment: thank you both. and the edit has corrected the problem